# My ListView is raising events that don't exist

Tags: asp.net, listview

So I have a listview:

```
<asp:listview runat="server" ID="listview_search" itemPlaceholderID="itemListing" DataSourceID="ds_search">
  <LayoutTemplate>
  <div id="sort" runat="server">
  <asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="sortByPrice" CommandName="sort" CommandArgument="price" >Sort by price</asp:LinkButton>
  </div>
  <div runat="server" id="itemListing"></div>
  </LayoutTemplate>


  <ItemTemplate>
     <div class="container profilelistings">
          <div class="row carousel-row">
              <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 slide-row" style="min-height: 100px;">
                   <div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide slide-carousel">
                                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                                        <div class="item active">
                                            <asp:Image id="img_car" imageurl='<%# "images/" + Eval("ownerID") + "/" + Eval("photo1") %>' runat="server"></asp:Image>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <div class="slide-content">
                                <h5><%# Eval("make").ToString() + " " + Eval("model") + " (" + Eval("type") + ") "  %></h5>
                                <h5><span class="price"><%# "£ " + Eval("price") %></span></h5>
                            </div>
                                 <div class="slide-footer">
                                    <span class="pull-right buttons">
                                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i> View more info </button>
                                    </span>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:listview>
```

When I click the sortByPrice LinkButton it gives an error "The ListView 'listview_search' raised event Sorting which wasn't handled." When the event does not exist in the ListView itself nor in the code.

Does anyone understand why it is doing this?

Comment: Hi, Your are binding the ListView with the DataSource and it is having the Allow Sorting property. So it is throwing an Error.

Comment: @LokeshBR Can you explain a bit more? I don't understand what you are saying

Comment: Hi, Change the CommandName in LinkButton to something else
CommandName="eClick" instead of CommandName="sort"

Comment: @LokeshBR I'm not using any event I am using the columns in the ListView along with the command names

Comment: You cannot use the CommandName="Sort" on LinkButton

Comment: @LokeshBR Then what can you use it on? I've seen hundreds of tutorials using a commandname="sort" on a linkButton for a listView

Comment: If you have Sorting enabled on the ListView then it works. SO change the commandname to something else.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.sorting(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @LokeshBR It works at the start, but when I dataBind my listView it doesn't work.